# Build hierarchy from strings C#

Tags: c#, string, lambda

I have a collection of strings:

```
"Alberton;Johannesburg"
"Allendale;Phoenix"
"Brackenhurst;Alberton"
"Cape Town;"
"Durban;"
"Johannesburg;"
"Mayville;Durban"
"Phoenix;Durban"
"Sandton;Johannesburg"
```

that I want to structure into a hierarchical structure in the fastest possible manner, like:

- Johannesburg

  - Alberton

    - Brackenhurst
  - Sandton
- Cape Town
- Durban

  - Phoenix

    - Allandale
  - Mayville

Currently I have nested for loops and checks, but was hoping I could achieve this with a single LAMBDA query?

The above mentioned strings are in a List.

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: What does the code that you `currently` have look like?

Comment: Because you think a single-line lambda will be inherently quicker? Well that's wrong.

Comment: I don't c any login in this hierachy

Comment: Nested for loops? Is the hierarchy fix or how deep can a tree be?

Comment: Just because lambda expression's look good on the eye, and used in most cases doesn't mean that they should be used all the time. There are no problems with having multiple loops, just not more than you need or in a bad way.

Comment: I wouldn't go with lambda for this (at least not a single statement). Makes it much harder to figure out what's up when there are problems.

Comment: Don't use lambda's because they look nice. Use what is most appropriate and readable. Can you first show us how you do it know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared lambda-like solution, but you should really think if it's more readable/efficient then your current one:

Helper Extension Method:

```
public static class ChildrenGroupExtensions
{
    public static List<CityInfo> GetChildren(this IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, City>> source, string parentName)
    {
        var cities = source.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Key == parentName);
        if (cities == null)
            return new List<CityInfo>();

        return cities.Select(c => new CityInfo { Name = c.Name, Children = source.GetChildren(c.Name) }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Helper Classes:

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
}

public class CityInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CityInfo> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var groups = (from i in items
                let s = i.Split(new[] { ';' })
                select new City { Name = s[0], Parent = s[1] }).GroupBy(e => e.Parent);


var root = groups.GetChildren(string.Empty);
```

Where `items` is your `List<string>`

You can look the results with simple helper method like that one:

```
private static void PrintTree(List<CityInfo> source, int level)
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        source.ForEach(c =>
        {
            Enumerable.Range(1, level).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write("\t"));
            Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
            PrintTree(c.Children, level + 1);
        });
    }
}
```

And the results are:

```
Cape Town
Durban
        Mayville
        Phoenix
                Allendale
Johannesburg
        Alberton
                Brackenhurst
        Sandton
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any specific data structure so I just used a class called Area with a list of children of itself. Also, it's in 2 lines of linq. There is also no check to see if an area is a child of 2 separate parents as the code is. Here's the code for the test I used(Relevant lines in-between the equals comments):

```
[TestFixture]
public class CitiesTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var strings = new List<string>
            {
                "Alberton;Johannesburg",
                "Allendale;Phoenix",
                "Brackenhurst;Alberton",
                "Cape Town;",
                "Durban;",
                "Johannesburg;",
                "Mayville;Durban",
                "Phoenix;Durban",
                "Sandton;Johannesburg"
            };

        //===================================================
        var allAreas = strings.SelectMany(x=>x.Split(';')).Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Distinct().ToDictionary(x=>x, x=>new Area{Name = x});

        strings.ForEach(area =>
            {
                var areas = area.Split(';');

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(areas[1]))
                    return;

                var childArea = allAreas[areas[0]];
                if (!allAreas[areas[1]].Children.Contains(childArea))
                    allAreas[areas[1]].Children.Add(childArea);

                childArea.IsParent = false;
            });

        var result = allAreas.Select(x=>x.Value).Where(x => x.IsParent);
        //===================================================
    }

    public class Area
    {
        public string Name;
        public bool IsParent;
        public List<Area> Children { get; set; }

        public Area()
        {
            Children = new List<Area>();
            IsParent = true;
        }
    }
}
```